# Remove part of the path in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, sed

```
echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed ????
```

What should be the Sed expression to get the output as

```
   /dir1/filename.txt
```

If there is any other simpler way to achieve this, that is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `cut`:

```
$ echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | cut -d/ -f1,2,4
/dir1/filename.txt
```

With `sed` it is a little mess:

```
$ echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed 's/^\(\/.*\)\(\/.*\)\(\/.*\)/\1\3/'
/dir1/filename.txt
```

The idea is to get portions of `/text` with `\(\/.*\)` and then print the ones we want, 1 and 3, with `\1\3`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick nicely `awk '{$(NF-1)=$NF;NF--}1' FS='/' OFS='/'`:

```
$ echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | awk '{$(NF-1)=$NF;NF--}1' FS='/' OFS='/' 
/dir1/filename.txt
```

The advantage here is the script is independent of the number of fields so given any number of folders the file is always moved into the parent directory.

```
$ echo "/a/b/c/d/e/f/filename.txt" | awk '{$(NF-1)=$NF;NF--}1' FS='/' OFS='/' 
/a/b/c/d/e/filename.txt
```

It works by setting the penultimate field `$(NF-)` to the last field `$NF` and reducing the number of fields `NF--`.

Comment: Good one! I like the generalisation (+1 for it), although the OP may want just the first and the last, not all but the penultimate.

Comment: @fedorqui The same thought occurred to me. The beauty with `awk` is a small modification to the spec doesn't mean re-writing the regexp from scratch. For just the first and last `awk '{$3=$NF;NF=3}1' FS='/' OFS='/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed 's:^\(.*\)/[^/]\+\(/[^/]\+\)$:\1\2:'
```

This will strip name of the last directory.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*\(\/.*\)/\1\2/'
```

or

```
echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed 's/\(.*\)\/[^/]*\//\1\//'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed 's/\/\w*//2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidharth C Nadhan said this
    echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed 's//\w*//2'
but to make it more readable use '!' (or something else).

```
$ echo "/dir1/dir2/filename.txt" | sed 's!/\w*/!/!'
/dir2/filename.txt
```

's!/\w*/!/!'   Meaning  Substitute /\w*/ with /
\w is a word-characer and * means any number.  '!' is a separator.
I added this even though the solution was accepted already,
but I think this is so much less-ugly that it's worth looking at.

Also, if this is for use in a bash script, bash is good at this stuff too,
and because it's built into bash it's in the same process and much more efficient.

```
$ f="/dir1/dir2/filename.txt";  echo $f; echo ${f/dir2\//}
/dir1/dir2/filename.txt
/dir1/filename.txt
```

Unfortunate you can't use something other than / as a separator, and I can't figure out how to make \w, or [^/]* or [a-z0-9]* or whatever work. Bash isn't as good as sed in that regard, and I don't know bash as well as I should.